# How to change background color of differnent countries in azure maps

Tags: azure-maps

I want to change the background color of Europe, America, and China with orange, blue, and red respectively. I have searched azure maps document and their demo example and I didn't find the answer. By default, all countries background color is in white color but I want to change it. Is it possible. If yes please help me.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Did you take a look at the Choropleth Map Sample? I believe this can help you understand how to paint regions of the map: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Demos/Create%20a%20Choropleth%20Map.html

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly, Found answer Thanks to [asergaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401038/asergaz).

I have created a codepen demo. --> codepen.io/pavanbn03/pen/LYLRpWo